# How to get actual triangles from DelaunayTriangulation[]?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, mesh

The `ComputationalGeometry` package has a [`DelaunayTriangulation[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ComputationalGeometry/ref/DelaunayTriangulation.html) function.  It returns a list of points connected to each point, ordered counterclockwise.

Example:

```
showTriangulation[tri_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Graphics[GraphicsComplex[points, Line /@ Thread /@ tri], opt]

points = Tuples[Range[0, 5, 1], 2];

tri = DelaunayTriangulation[points];
showTriangulation[tri]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question:** How can I obtain a list of all *triangles* instead?

---

My first naive first try doesn't work correctly:

```
makeTriangles[points_] := 
 Flatten[Function[{p, list}, 
    Prepend[#, p] & /@ Partition[list, 2, 1, {1, 1}]] @@@ 
   DelaunayTriangulation[points], 1] (* doesn't work *)

GraphicsComplex[points, Line@makeTriangles[points]] // Graphics
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why does it give an incorrect result?

This function simply takes all points $\{A, B, C, D, \ldots\}$ connected to a point $P$, and constructs the triangles $PAB, PBC, PCD, \ldots$.  Since $A,B,C,...$ are in counterclockwise order, I assumed all these would be valid triangles.  But take the following case:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

$PAB$ will not be a valid triangle, even though $ABC$ are in counterclockwise order.

Comment: I already realized that I don't actually need this for my work, but I though some might find the question interesting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It might be easier to use [TriangularSurfacePlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ComputationalGeometry/ref/TriangularSurfacePlot.html) to find the Delaunay triangulation of the points. For example,

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
triangles[points_] := Module[{pl},
  pl = TriangularSurfacePlot[ArrayPad[points, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]];
  Cases[pl, Polygon[a_] :> Flatten[(Position[points, #[[{1, 2}]]] & /@ a)], 
    Infinity]]

Graphics[GraphicsComplex[points, {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[],    
  Polygon[triangles[points]]}]]
```

produces this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

If we use the approach in the original question, each valid triangle should appear exactly trice in the list, so a way to extract the triangles from the result of `DelaunayTriangulation` would be

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
triangles2[points_] := Module[{tr, triples},
  tr = DelaunayTriangulation[points];
  triples = Flatten[Function[{v, list},
      Switch[Length[list],
        (* account for nodes with connectivity 2 or less *)
        1, {},
        2, {Flatten[{v, list}]}, 
        _, {v, ##} & @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1, {1, 1}]
      ]
    ] @@@ tr, 1];
  Cases[GatherBy[triples, Sort], a_ /; Length[a] == 3 :> a[[1]]]]
```

**Edit**

I've moved `` Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"] `` outside of the function definition of triangles. As Szabolcs correctly remarked in his comments, putting `` Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"] `` inside the definition will cause shadowing problems because of the creation of the symbol `` Global`DelaunayTriangulation ``

**Edit 2**

Apparently `ListDensityPlot` uses a Delaunay triangulation as well, and is much faster than `TriangularSurfacePlot`, so the first part of this answer could be made much more efficient by rewriting it according to

```
triangles1[points_] := Module[{pl},
  pl = ListDensityPlot[ArrayPad[points, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]];
  Cases[pl, Polygon[a_] :> a, Infinity][[1]]]
```

Note that since `ListDensityPlot` returns a `GraphicsComplex` and it keeps the order of the points the same, the index lists for the polygons can extracted directly from the plot without having to lookup the indices of the vertices in `points`.

Comment: A comment on putting the `Needs` inside the function definition: this will only work if you explicitly include the context names in the symbols, i.e. use ``ComputationalGeometry`DelaunayTriangulation``.  This is because the context of symbols is determined at parse time.  When the function definition is evaluated in a fresh kernel, the package is not loaded yet, so there's no `DelaunayTriangulation` symbol yet.  But as soon as Mathematica sees this symbol in the definition, it creates it---in the ``Global` `` context.  When the function is called for the first time, ...

Comment: ... the package will be loaded, but ``ComputationalGeometry`DelaunayTriangulation`` will be shadowed by ``Global`DelaunayTriangulation``.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917550/why-doesnt-this-use-of-begin-work) (finally found it).

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, I didn't realise about `Needs[...]` inside function definitions. I guess I missed it because I had already loaded the package in the same session.

Comment: Can you edit the answer please?

Comment: @Szabolcs Done.

Comment: We can get a significant speedup using `ListDensityPlot` instead of `TriangularSurfacePlot`.  Mathematica already has a very fast implementation of Delaunay triangulation (use for plotting), but it does not expose it to users directly...  Now the bottleneck will be `Cases`, I'll have to think about how to speed that up.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's good to know. I had noticed that the triangulations of both functions looked suspiciously similar, but I wasn't sure if `ListDensityPlot` always returns a Delaunay triangulation. I think I can come up with something for `Cases` using `Sow` and `Reap`.

Comment: @Szabolcs actually, since `ListDensityPlot` returns a `GraphicsComplex`, you there is no need for the `Position` bit in the `Cases` statement so it should be fast anyway.

Comment: @Heike any idea on how would you go about extracting the triangles in 3D around ListContourPlot3D? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In Mathematica 10, you can use `DelaunayMesh` on a set of points. This returns a `MeshRegion`. You can use `MeshCoordinates` to return a list of coordinates of the points (should be the same as the initial set of points) and then `MeshCells` to return the triangles.

See [Interactive Computational Geometry](http://www.clearviewtraining.com/interactive-computational.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

### Update

It seems that the simplest way to find Delaunay triangles is to read them off from Voronoi diagram. Here is only two lines of code:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]  

listSow[{pt_, list_}] := Scan[Sow[pt, #] &, list];

DelaunayTriangles[pts_] := Select[
Last@Reap@Scan[listSow, Last@VoronoiDiagram[pts]], (Length[#] == 3) &]
```

Application is as follows:

```
npts = 100;
pts = Transpose@{RandomReal[{0, 2}, npts], RandomReal[{0, 1}, npts]};

Graphics@GraphicsComplex[pts,
{{FaceForm@None, EdgeForm@LightGray,Polygon/@ DelaunayTriangles[pts]}, {Red, Point@Range@npts}}]
```

[image]

### Obsolete part

I just would like to notice that the part of Heike's answer, there `DelaunayTriangulation` is used, is not completely correct. Let me demonstrate it with a simple example:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]  
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {1/2, 1/(2 Sqrt[3])}};  
delaunayGraph = DelaunayTriangulation[pts];
```

Let's now find the graph edges

```
edges = Join@@Table[Thread[{v, Select[delaunayGraph[[v, 2]], # > v &]}], {v, 1, Length[pts] - 1}];
```

and depict them

```
Graphics[{Line@pts[[#]] & /@ edges, {Red, PointSize -> Medium, Point[pts]},  
FontSize -> 14, MapIndexed[Inset[First@#2, #1, {Right, Bottom}] &, pts]}]
```

[image]

It is easy to see that the triangle {1,2,3} appears also thrice in Heike's list.

```
triangles2[pts]  
(* {{1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 4}} *)
```

Probably, the triangular convex hull is the only such example. In any case here is my "brute force" solution:

```
area[v1_, v2_] := Det[Subtract @@@ {v1, v2}]  

findSmallest[{a_, b_}, list_] := First@SortBy[list, Abs@area[pts[[{#, b}]], pts[[{a, b}]]] &]

findPartners[{a_, b_}, list_] := findSmallest[{a, b}, #] & /@  
GatherBy[list, Sign@area[pts[[{#, b}]], pts[[{a, b}]]] &] 

tri[a_, b_] := Sequence @@ (Sort[{a, #, b}] & /@ 
 findPartners[{a, b}, Intersection[delaunayGraph[[a, 2]], delaunayGraph[[b, 2]]]]);

triples = Union[tri @@@ edges]  
(* {{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}} *)
```

The idea is as follows: firstly, for an every edge `{a,b}` we find additional vertices attached to it (they form triangle with the edge), see `Intersection` in `tri`. Then we gather these vertices according to parts of the plane divided by the edge linear continuation, see `GatherBy` in `findPartners`. Finally, we find the triangle of the smallest area in each part of the plane, see `SortBy` in `findSmallest`.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
triangles[vertices_] := 
    DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Flatten[Partition[#[[2]], 2, 1] /.
                     {x_Integer, y_Integer} :> {#[[1]], x, y} & /@ vertices, 1]]
```

(using `Partition[]` to make lists of triangles with three vertices instead of four)

```
In[95]:= triangles[tri]
Out[95]= {{1,7,8},{1,2,8},{2,8,9},{2,3,9},{3,9,10},{3,4,10},{4,10,11},{4,5,11},{5,11,12},{5,6,12},{7,13,14},{7,8,14},{8,14,15},{8,9,15},{9,15,16},{9,10,16},{10,16,17},{10,11,17},{11,17,18},{11,12,18},{13,19,20},{13,14,20},{14,20,21},{14,15,21},{15,21,22},{15,16,22},{16,22,23},{16,17,23},{17,23,24},{17,18,24},{19,25,26},{19,20,26},{20,26,27},{20,21,27},{21,27,28},{21,22,28},{22,28,29},{22,23,29},{23,29,30},{23,24,30},{25,31,32},{25,26,32},{26,32,33},{26,27,33},{27,33,34},{27,28,34},{28,34,35},{28,29,35},{29,35,36},{29,30,36}}

Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Thickness[Medium]],
   (* the triangles *) GraphicsComplex[points, Polygon[triangles[tri]]],
   (* and their labels *) MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], Mean[#1 /. Thread[Range@Length@tri -> points]]] &, triangles[tri]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is the same what I did (with minor variations) and has the same problem.  Not all of the points that are connected to a given point need to be connected together, not even if they are adjacent in the counterclockwise order.

Comment: Just test on `points = Tuples[{0, 1}, 2]; tri = {{1, {2, 3, 4}}, {2, {1, 4}}, {3, {4, 1}}, {4, {2, 1, 3}}}; DelaunayTriangulationQ[points, tri]`.  This is a manually constructed example, but it is a valid triangulation, and I think there's no guarantee something like this won't be returned by `DelaunayTriangulation[]`.

Comment: I should have explained a bit better what was wrong with my original (flawed) implementation.  I have now updated the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I tried the DelaunayTriangulation directly on your points, and I get a different triangulation than your example: same points in each list, but the last list {{4,{2,1,3}} is a cyclic permutation in the numbers of the first list {{1,{3,4,2}}). And this one works with my code, while yours does not. I wonder if it possible to prove whether DT will always return lists whose repeated elements are cyclic permutations only. (If that makes any sense!)

Comment: Yes, I constructed the example by hand to show that your function is not robust.  This data is also a valid triangulation, and the points are still in counterclockwise order.  I cannot trust that DelaunayTriangulation won't ever return such a result because according to the documentation any cyclic permutation of the points is a possible output (i.e. it mentions no restrictions).