# Create triangular mesh from random list of points

Tags: graphics, random, computational-geometry, mesh

I have a list of points. I would like to take these points and create a mesh of triangles from them, making sure triangles don't overlap. So here's a list of points:

```
p0 = Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, 10}, {100}], RandomReal[{0, 12}, {100}]}];
ListPlot@p0
```

[image]

Now I've managed to take the first point in the list, find its two nearest neighbours and construct a triangle from this:

```
Graphics[{Thick, Red, Line[Append[Nearest[p0, p0[[1, All]], 3], p0[[1, All]]]]}]
```

[image]

What I'd not like to do is from this starting point keep connecting points to make a mesh where all the triangle corners are at one of the points and no triangles overlap. Any suggestions on how to do this?

--*Below may be irrelevant*--

I imagine `DelaunayTriangulation` might come into this, however I'm not sure how. Also when I run it I don't understand what it returns:

```
DelaunayTriangulation[p0] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: p.s. It doesn't really seem productive to forbid new users from submitting images and posting more than 2 links. It just makes it harder to explain the question! So I apologise for the links to images and the third link at the bottom which requires removing [take this out] for the link to work :)

Comment: Don't worry about the images, people here are usually helpful on solve this issue. I've shortened your Q as it cointained some irrelevant overhead, please feel free to roll back the edit if you find it incorrect.

Comment: Delaunay is the way to go. You will need to use those index lists to create the list of triangle segments.

Comment: You now have two upvotes and with them, the vaunted power to post images!  Please post responsibly. :)

Comment: @MarkMcClure haha fantastic. Just wrapping my brain round your answer. Think I have enough information to figure it out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, you can generate your random points like so:

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomReal[{0, 12}, {100, 2}];
```

The `DelaunayTriangulation` command returns an [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) representation of the triangulation.

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
dt = DelaunayTriangulation[pts];
dt // Column
```

[image]

This says that the first point should be connected to the 2nd, the 24th, etc.  Given `{u, {v1,v2,v3,___}}`, we need a `toPairs` function to form `{{u,v1},{u,v2},{u,v3},___}`.  We then need to map `toPairs` onto the triangulation and `Flatten` that result one level.  This is all accomplished as follows.

```
toPairs[{m_, ns_List}] := Map[{m, #} &, ns];
edges = Flatten[Map[toPairs, dt], 1];
```

Finally, we visualize using a `GraphicsComplex`.

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[pts, {Line[edges], 
  Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Any chance you could briefly describe each step and I'll try and understand what's going on? Thank you. (Each step from "toPairs" onwards)

Comment: @ThomasJebbSturges Does the edit help?

Comment: This may be useful too: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277/how-to-get-actual-triangles-from-delaunaytriangulation

Comment: @MarkMcClure It was tough but I've managed to comprehend it. Go me. What a concise way of doing it! Thank you kindly :)

Comment: @ThomasJebbSturges No problem!

Comment: Slight mod to assigning edges indicies `edges = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Flatten[Map[toPairs, dt], 1]];` halves the number of links, more importantly it ensures a set of unique links (that you visualize and) that OP will be needing in the iterations of his algorithm.

Answer (score 14):

There are some new functions in Mathematica 10 that make this very easy:

```
r = {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}};
pts = RandomSample[Permutations[Range[-5, 5], {2}], 10];
Grid[{
  {"The sites", "Delaunay trianguation", "Voronoi diagram"},
  {
   Graphics[{Red, Point[pts]}, PlotRange -> r],
   Show[dm = DelaunayMesh[ pts], Graphics[{Red, Point[pts]}], 
   PlotRange -> r],
   Show[VoronoiMesh[ pts], Graphics[{Red, Point[pts]}], PlotRange -> r]
   }
  }, Frame -> All]

Head[dm]
MeshCoordinates[ dm ]
MeshCells[ dm , 2]
MeshCells[ dm , 2][[ All, 1]]
```

[image: DelaunayTraingulation]

```
MeshRegion

{{-5., -4.}, {3., -4.}, {5., -2.}, {4., 0.}, {-4., -1.}, 
{-3., 2.}, {0., -1.}, {3., -5.}, {2., 4.}, {5., -5.}}

{Polygon[{5, 1, 7}], Polygon[{6, 7, 9}], Polygon[{7, 6, 5}], 
 Polygon[{9, 7, 4}], Polygon[{1, 8, 7}], Polygon[{8, 10, 2}], 
 Polygon[{2, 3, 4}], Polygon[{3, 2, 10}], Polygon[{2, 4, 7}], 
 Polygon[{8, 2, 7}]}

{{5, 1, 7}, {6, 7, 9}, {7, 6, 5}, {9, 7, 4}, {1, 8, 7}, {8, 10, 
  2}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 2, 10}, {2, 4, 7}, {8, 2, 7}}
```

So you use `DelaunayMesh` to create a `MeshRegion` from the point set, and then you can use `MeshCells` as shown to get the triangles. `MeshCells` gives you triples of indexes into the `MeshCoordinates`.

I took the above code from [Interactive Computational Geometry](http://www.clearviewtraining.com/interactive-computational.html) (disclaimer - I am the author).

Answer (score 11):

It seems you are asking for the [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).

There's a function for this in the Computational Geometry package, which Mark described.

Another, usually much faster option is using `ListDensityPlot`:

```
ldp = ListDensityPlot[ArrayPad[p0, {0, {0, 1}}], Mesh -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> (White &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can extract the polygons from this graphic if needed.

```
Cases[ldp, Polygon[idx_] :> idx, Infinity]
```

This will return the triangles as point index triplets.

You can also use the [undocumented function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13521/12) `ListDensityPlot` relies on, if you wish.

Comment: This looks like a neat way of doing it. Thank you for the response. It took me long enough to wrap my small brain around Marks answer so I'll stick with what I (now) know!

Comment: Hmm... I can't decide whether I like this or not.  I guess I better upvote, just in case.

Comment: @Mark I don't like it, but it's definitely much faster than using the package function.  I used it for a while with [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216/adaptive-sampling-for-slow-to-compute-functions-in-2d), because DelaunayTriangulation was too slow.

Comment: @Szabolcs It's just that `ListDensityPlot` is about the last thing I would've thought of.  Back in the day, this returned a `DensityGraphics` object.  I guess it now returns a `GraphicsComplex` with polygons. I use the `Graphics`\``Mesh` stuff all the time, though.

Comment: @MarkMcClure It's probably better to use ``Graphics`Mesh`` instead.  After all the structure returned by `ListDensityPlot` is also undocumented and it may change at any time.  So my effort to avoid mentioning undocumented functions was a bit misguided I guess.

Comment: @Szabolcs Hey, I upvoted! I *was* joking when I said I wasn't sure if I liked it.

Comment: @Mark But I do agree that while it's practical, it's not a nice way ... I was always annoyed by having to extract data from the output of plotting functions because there's no public API to access the underlying methods ...  For example I'd love to have access to the adaptive sampling algorithm used by two-variable plotting functions.  I'd also love to have a documented and fast Delaunay triangulator.  There would be so many applications ... I don't want to rely too much on undocumented things for code that I may need to use a few years later.

Comment: @Mark [Here's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8724/12) yet another example where I used plotting functions for numerical calculations.  It would be so valuable to have direct access to the underlying numerical methods and to be able to tune them and use them for calculations, not only for plotting.

Comment: Great! It's a speed-up of 150 and more (164 for 5k points on my comp). This would make the algorithm OP is coding (recalculating triangulation over and over) useful actually. Little Q though: is anything in Graphics`Mesh even faster (for I am not familiar with the package; for example, how can I get a list of functions there?)?

Comment: `?Graphics(backtick)Mesh(backtick)*` // I think I get the function list part.

Comment: @BoLe According to my benchmarking there's a problem with the complexity of the algorithm used for triangulation by Mma's plotting functions: it doesn't look like $O(n \log n)$ which it should be ...  Around 10000-30000 points you'll hit a wall and you won't be able to go much higher.  If you need to triangulate a lot, I suggest you look for ways to connect to external libraries.  Try e.g. [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13445/12) (though Qhull isn't too speedy either)

Comment: Wov. The Qhull `qDelaunayTriangulation` is faster for another order. My timing (5k points; same output, ie. triangle indicies): `DelaunayTriangulation` - 133 s; via `ListDensityPlot` - 0.784 s; `Qhull` - 0.049 s. That are speed-up factors 170 from first route to the second and another 16 to the third (or 2700 from Mma's built-in to the linked Qhull). Now you're mentioning there're even faster triangulators, like Triangle; they could be linked into Mma in the same way (compilation, MathLink), right?