# Coloring a set of polygons, each polygon to have a specific color

Tags: graphics3d, color

In addition to my previous post, [regarding plotting the surface of a Möbius strip](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52295/problem-regarding-3d-plot-of-a-moebius-strip-from-a-set-of-2d-points), I now realised, that some of the eigenmodes for a Möbius strip are either oscillations of a scalar field OR a vector field, meaning that not all eigenmodes of this object can be shown in 3D as wobbles in the direction normal to the surface, because the Möbius strip is not orientable, like a cylinder is.

Now that I have learned this fact, I have to do the following:

1. Represent all **transversal** oscillations as wobbles in the direction normal to the surface. This means that these are oscillations of a vector field with only one component. This has been successfully done with the help in my previous question.
2. I need to represent all the **longitudinal** oscillations as oscillations of a scalar field, which is usually done by showing changes of color on an object, like shown in this example for a cylinder:
   [image: cylinder example]

**Problem**

I would like to plot 4D data $(x,y,z,F)$ as a set of polygons that have been made using `DelaunayTriangulation[]` of a 2D mesh in 3D using `Graphics3D`for the case of a Möbius strip, where $(x,y,z)$ are the data points and $F$ is the color.

In my previous question I noted that `ListSurfacePlot3D` and `ListPlot3D` are not working properly for the case of the Möbius strip. The solution was to plot the strip as a set of polygons, generated by the mesh. A uniformly colored polygon surface looks like this:
[image: Möbius strip]

**What I want**

I would like to color these polygons with the color equal to the average value of $F$ for the surrounding 3 points.

**Here is the provided data and code**

Original 2D data of a rectangular $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ membrane:

```
data2D = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/0Liw8F1r", "NB"];
```

Transformed 4D data parametrised as a Möbius strip with color data as the 4th column:

```
data4D = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/zgrCRiQh", "NB"];
```

The code to draw the strip without the color data $F$:

```
tri = First @ Cases[ListDensityPlot[Join[#, {0}] & /@ data2D], 
                    Polygon[idx_] :> idx, Infinity];    

Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[data4D[[;; , 1 ;; 3]], {Yellow, EdgeForm[], Polygon /@ tri}], 
           Boxed -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
           SphericalRegion -> True, , ImageSize -> Large,
           PlotRange -> 0.9 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-0.5, 0.5}}]
```

I tried to find some answers before posting the question, but all solutions had either discrete points or smooth plots in 3D, and I need to color the specific polygons.

Thank you all for your help, I hope that the problem is clearly stated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
data2D = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0Liw8F1r", "NB"];
data4D = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zgrCRiQh", "NB"];
```

Find `min` and `max` values for the color data

```
{min, max} = {Min[#], Max[#]} &@data4D[[All, -1]];
```

Now, I place a color in front of each polygon (like {color1, polygon1, color2, polygon2, ...}) when specifying the graphics used by `GraphicsComplex`.  The color1 is the average of the color data (according to `data4D`) specified at each vertex of polygon1.

```
Labeled[Graphics3D[
  GraphicsComplex[
   data4D[[;; , 1 ;; 3]], {EdgeForm[], 
    Map[{ColorData["DarkRainbow"][
        Rescale[Mean[Part[data4D, #1, -1]], {min, max}]], 
       Polygon[#1]} &, tri]}], Boxed -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, SphericalRegion -> True, 
  PlotRange -> 0.9 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], 
 BarLegend[{"DarkRainbow", {min, max}}], Right]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I wanted. I had trouble getting the point data from the corresponding indices in a certain polygon. Thank's a lot!

Comment: Is it just me, or does this take a lot of time to plot?

EDIT: Oh, nevermind, found the typo!

Comment: Is there a way to include interpolation though? Or somehow remove the shading on this polygons?

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, one can use `DelaunayMesh[]` directly for mesh triangulation instead of `ListDensityPlot[]`:

```
data2D = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0Liw8F1r", "NB"];
data4D = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zgrCRiQh", "NB"];

pts = Drop[data4D, None, -1];

dm = DelaunayMesh[data2D];
tri = First /@ MeshCells[dm, 2];

nrms = Table[Flatten[Last[SingularValueDecomposition[Standardize[pts[[t]], Mean, 1 &],
                                                     -1, Tolerance -> 0]]], {t, tri}];

vc = ColorData["DarkRainbow"] /@ Rescale[data4D[[All, -1]]];
vn = Table[Normalize[Mean[nrms[[id]]]], {id, dm["VertexFaceConnectivity"]}];

Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts, {EdgeForm[], Polygon[tri2]},
                           VertexColors -> vc, VertexNormals -> vn],
           Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral",
           PlotRange -> 0.9 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image: colored Möbius strip]

The clash of bright and dark colors is due to the nonorientability, which is manifested in the directions of the estimated normals. (See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14218) for another illustration.)