# How to generate 2D FEM mesh in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh, tetgenlink

To generate 3D mesh [TetGen](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/TetGenLink/tutorial/UsingTetGenLink.html#167310445) can be easily used. Are there similar functions (or a way to use TetGen) to generate 2d mesh? I know that such functionality can be [easily implemented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22244/creating-a-2d-meshing-algorithm-in-mathematica) but I would like to use a Mathematica provided function, as I need to experiment with number of nodes in elements and so on. I just want to solve PDE using FEM not really to play around with mesh generation.

Comment: `DelaunayTriangulation` might be of interest.

Comment: I think the short answer is no, there is no intrinsic capability.  Use one of the algorithms in the question you linked, or generate externally and import.  If by "number of nodes" you mean "other than triangular" then external packages really are the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Since Mathematica 10.3 ToElementMesh[] function can be used, along with FEM solver. For details see [this link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use TetGen and just make a z axis which is set to 0 (or any other constant).  The issue with DelaunayTriangulation (if you want to generate a mesh from a list of points) is that it returns an adjacency list of the edges, which is very hard to turn into the polygons.  [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277/how-to-get-actual-triangles-from-delaunaytriangulation) thread describes the issue with it.

Adding a z dimention of 0 is simply:

```
pts3d = Map[Append[#, 0]&, pts2d]
```

And then to turn the 3d points back into 2d:

```
newpts2d = pts3d[[All,1;;2]]
```

Comment: I'm not sure about using TetGen, as it returns non-zero code when plane is given to be meshed.

Comment: @Mark, I'd be very interested to see a more complete example, could you provide one?

Comment: This fails `TetGenDelaunay[{1, 1, 0} # & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 3}]]`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use Imtek's package.  These deal with both 2 and 3D with interfaces to Shewchuck's triangle and Tetgen respectively.

Imtek can be had from [the University of Freiburg](http://portal.uni-freiburg.de/imteksimulation/downloads/ims).  Documentation is extensive.